# "et al" usage question migration

Tags: discussion, migration

Someone recently asked a question on Academia related to [the usage of "et al" in a sentence](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/7194/73). We closed it as off-topic, and we want to know whether it's fit for a migration to your site.

Comment: Probably ok here at ELU, but flag it to have one of tour mods talk to one of our mods to do yhe migration.

Comment: @Mitch The mods are on tour this year? Kewl!  Where do I get tickies?

Comment: @Mitch I'm a mod on Academia, so I took the liberty of just sending it on over. Thanks!

Comment: @tchrist: I think tou'll notice a conservation of y's and t's in thay.